# Moving from GridView to GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I am trying to move my app from using GridView to using RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager.  I am new to RecylcerViews, but have successfully converted my ListViews, now working on my GridView.  A couple things I am unsure about:

My current GridView has a certain number of columns, determined at runtime, with each grid column the same, hard-coded width.  It is scrollable both horizontally and vertically (I wrap my Gridview in a HorizontalScrollView).  So I basically need to have a view with a set number of columns that are a set width, irrespective of screen width.

I have been having problems finding a method to set the column(span) width for GridLayoutManager, so I assume that is not how GridLayoutManager.  It almost sounds like it is built to always fit all columns on the screen, rather than letting them spill off the screen?  What is the best way to tell GridLayoutManager that I want, for example, 6 columns that are each 150 units wide (either dp or pixels)?

For scrolling in both directions, it sounds like I can use my current approach and just wrap my RecyclerView in a HorizontalScrollView, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the width of the `RecyclerView` `wrap_content` and set the number of spans you want. (Make sure parents of the `RecyclerView` are also `wrap_content`.) When you create the item views in the `RecyclerView`'s `onCreateViewHolder()` make sure that it is the width that you want. The `RecyclerView` will grow to the width of the view holder layout times the number of spans.

All you need to do now is to wrap everything in a `HorizontalScrollView`.